# Finding the previous value and creating a new column in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataset and I want to go back and see the previous value that has changed by group and creating a new column with the previous value.

Sample Data:

```
 Group  Value        
   01    10
   01    10
   01    10
   02    5
   02    5
   02    15
   03    20
   03    25
   03    15
   03    15
```

Desired Output:

```
Group     Value    Previous_Value
 01         10                 
 01         10     
 01         10
 02         5
 02         5
 02         15          5 
 03         20
 03         25         20
 03         15         25
 03         15
```

I have imported pandas and numpy for this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
# the previous values
shifted = df.groupby('Group')['Value'].shift()

# mask the values only where the `Value` changes, not the `Group` changes
df['Previous_Value'] = shifted.where(shifted.notna() & shifted.ne(df['Value']))
```

Output:

```
   Group  Value  Previous_Value
0      1     10             NaN
1      1     10             NaN
2      1     10             NaN
3      2      5             NaN
4      2      5             NaN
5      2     15             5.0
6      3     20             NaN
7      3     25            20.0
8      3     15            25.0
9      3     15             NaN
```